# Read/Use variables from another javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

If I import a js file like this :

```
const importedFile = require( './file1');
```

I can see all my functions and console logs of file1 running, but I can't run or use a specific variable

If I `console.log( importedFile )` I get this : `{}` empty object !

How to get all variables from file1.js ?

Comment: you cannot change const value

Comment: Noone is trying to change. just to read..

Comment: Have a read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @DarrenSweeney — That's ES6 imports, not the Node module system.

Comment: From that link I tried this:
import  * as importedFile from './file1.js';
Gives me this: SyntaxError: Unexpected token *

Comment: @Quentin Ah yes, apologies, my eyes ignored the `node.js` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, in file1  I can export variables like this :

```
function thisIsAFunction() {
    let var1 = { qty: 123 }
    let var2 = { qty: 123 }
    let var3 = { qty: 123 }

    return [ var1, var2, var3 ];
}
module.exports = {
    thisIsAFunction
}
```

Then read/use the first variable like this:

```
let importedValue= importedFunct.thisIsAFunction()

console.log(  importedValue[0][0].qty)
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript modules are self-contained environments with their own scope.

Only explicitly exported values are available outside of the module.

So, if you want something in `./file1` to be available in `importedFile`, then you need to include it in the exports:

```
const value = "Hello, world";

function thisIsAFunction() {
    console.log(value);
}

module.exports = {
    thisIsAFunction
}
```

Then you can:

```
const importedFile = require( './file1');
importedFile.thisIsAFunction();
```

Comment: Yes I was able to import one variable, but as I said I can see everything running, but I can't use anything, why is that? Is there any way to export all variables ?

Comment: No. You can't export variables, only values.

Comment: Yeah all variable values, all together, not just one. And another problem is that in file1 my variables values change every 10 secs, but when I try to import I get only the first value

Comment: As I said, you can only export values, not variables. You can export a function that gives you their current values on demand. And you can put as many values in the object you export as you like.

Comment: Ah okay, but if the ' const value = "Hello, world"; ' was declared inside the function, how to read it then? Cause I need to read/use not just console.log it

Comment: @itneg — Replace `console.log(value)` with whatever you like. It's a function. It does whatever functions do.

Comment: I tried to put the ' const value = "Hello, world"; ' inside the function , and call it like this
' console.log( importedFile.thisIsAFunction().value ) ', it says : TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined..
I want to use it, if the value was a number I want to make some calculations , not just view in console..

Comment: Constants inside functions are not properties of functions. If you want to use it inside the function then you would just put something like `return value + 27` inside the function.

Comment: You might want to find an introductory JS tutorial before you try to get to grips with modules.